# Chaining observables in reactivex

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactivex

I have the following scenario and I need to transform it in RxJava:

1. get 30 items from local db
2. call an api with those 30 entries (one request)
3. remove the items from local db (this needs access to the items list)
4. loop (?) I'd like to repeat 1-3 this until db is empty

What I've done so far looks like this:

```
fetchAllFromDbObservable()
    .flatMap( (string) -> {
        return Model
    })
    .buffer(30)
    .publish( (List<Model>, Response) -> {
        return callApiObservable(List<Model>);  
    })
    .publish( (Response) -> {
        // how do I get access here to List<Model> ?
        ArrayList<Long> ids = getIdsFromList(List<Model>)
        return removeFromDbObservable(ids);  
    })
```

Questions:

1. is publish the right thing to call or should I use when/and/then?
2. how can I pass the model list from one observable to another?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation of your requirements may be as follows:

```
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Looper {

    // initialize db with 100 items
    private final List<Integer> db = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
            .boxed().collect(toList());

    private List<Integer> read30ItemsFromDb() {
        return db.stream().limit(30).collect(toList());
    }

    private void makeApiCall(List<Integer> items) {
        System.out.println(items);
    }

    private void removeFromDb(List<Integer> itemsToBeRemoved) {
        db.removeAll(itemsToBeRemoved);
    }

    private enum Command { NEXT }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Looper looper = new Looper();

        PublishSubject<Command> itemsProducer = PublishSubject.create();
        PublishSubject<List<Integer>> itemsConsumer = PublishSubject.create();

        itemsProducer.subscribe(command -> {
            switch (command) {
                case NEXT:
                    List<Integer> items = looper.read30ItemsFromDb();
                    if (!items.isEmpty()) itemsConsumer.onNext(items);
                    else itemsConsumer.onCompleted();
                default:
                    itemsConsumer.onCompleted();
            }
        });

        itemsConsumer
                .doOnCompleted(itemsProducer::onCompleted)
                .subscribe(items -> {
                    looper.makeApiCall(items);
                    looper.removeFromDb(items);
                    itemsProducer.onNext(Command.NEXT);
                });

        // start the loop
        itemsProducer.onNext(Command.NEXT);
    }
}
```